# Having trouble with Box2D getContactList used via LibGDX

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I'm having some trouble in that it seems like some of the contacts that `getContactList` is returning aren't actually contacts.

Relevant code:

```
    List < Contact > contacts = theBall.body.getWorld().getContactList(); //get all contacts in current world
    if (contacts.size() == 0) selected = -1; // if there are no contacts, set selected to -1, meaning no menu item is selected

    /* loop through all contacts */
    for (Contact con: contacts) {
        Fixture fixtureA = con.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fixtureB = con.getFixtureB();
        LogapPlatform lplat = LogapUtils.cast(fixtureA.getBody().getUserData(), fixtureB.getBody().getUserData(), LogapPlatform.class);
        LogapBall lball = LogapUtils.cast(fixtureA.getBody().getUserData(), fixtureB.getBody().getUserData(), LogapBall.class);

        /* check if the contact is between a LogapBall object and a LogapPlatform object */
        if (lball != null && lplat != null) {
            /* if true, determine which of the five menu platforms the ball has been placed on top of */
            for (int i = 0; i < LogapLevel.ctrPlat.size(); i++) {
                if (lplat.equals(LogapLevel.ctrPlat.get(i)) && (lball.getPos().y > lplat.getPos().y)) {
                    selected = (int) Math.floor(i / 5); // set selected to the "id" of the selected menu platform
                }
            }
        } else {
            selected = -1; // if false, set selected to -1
        }
    }

    /* "NEW GAME" is the only menu item currently implemented. its "id" = 2 */
    if (selected == 2)
        LogapGame.font.setColor(Color.YELLOW); // if the ball is placed on top of the menu platform for NEW GAME, set the font color of the text to yellow
    else
        LogapGame.font.setColor(Color.PINK); // else, keep the text pink

     /* draw the text on the screen */
     if (logLev.menuLevel) {
        LogapGame.font.draw(batch, "NEW GAME", 135, 150);
        LogapGame.font.setColor(LogapGame.GRAY_192);
    }
```

To see this code in action (and the trouble I'm having), here's a video sample to illustrate (I have Box2DDebugRenderer enabled btw):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcHwt4b4lt0

So, as you may already see, the problem I'm having is that the text turns to yellow even though the ball has not yet come in contact with the platform. What's supposed to happen is that the text should only turn yellow when the ball comes in contact with the platform. If there's any doubt whether or not they aren't in fact, in contact, here's a closeup:

[sample http://static.rateyourmusic.com/lk/l/w/02413fc8b4aef5d9f37c3b12420d4a2d/4870735.png](http://static.rateyourmusic.com/lk/l/w/02413fc8b4aef5d9f37c3b12420d4a2d/4870735.png)

Any idea as to why the text is changing color even though the two objects aren't in contact yet?

*P.S. - For anyone wondering why I'm not using a collision listener, well, I am. Just not for this specific logic. I ran into some quirks with collision listener so I decided that for some of the behavior of objects in the game, I'd rather manually query the contacts like this.*

Comment: *"Relevant code:"*  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: Excuse me? Everything I've mentioned in the question and the code that was included is completely relevant to the issue that I'm experiencing.

Comment: *"is completely relevant.."*  Excuse you, I never said it wasn't!  An SSCCE can be *longer* that what is seen above, but concentrate on the *rest* of the letters.. SC, C & an E (which that posted code, ..is none of).

Comment: How is that posted code not an example of the problem I am experiencing? It clearly shows that I got all the contacts via getContactList() and looped through them, checked for the contact I want to check, but the program is not behaving in the way I expect.

Comment: "Make sure the code you post displays the problem!"

It displays the problem.

Comment: It is an example of a runtime problem when it compiles cleanly, and display the problem for others.  But I get the impression you just want to argue about it, so..  Don't stress it.  Good luck with it.

Comment: If you require that it be runnable for others so they could see the problem for themselves, I'd have to post my entire project or at least whip up something that includes libgdx and will work in the same way, which is something I wouldn't do right off the bat if I can communicate my problem without doing so. That's why there is an accompanying video and image, so that the problem is illustrated as clearly as possible.

"I am not proposing that every single problem needs a SSCCE in order to be solved." --- I agree. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Box2D with libGDX, but I have used it extensively with other engines (usually C++ based ones) and it will not be much different.

The first question I got is
 - "Why do you not use the contact listener callbacks in order to get the information about the happening collisions ?"

GetContactList returns all POSSIBLE contacts. What that means is that the two bodies AABB's have been penetrated, but not necessarily the fixtures have collided.

It's better to use the contact listener in general for that stuff.
You can have a bit more read about the collision and contact listener over here:
[iForce2D Box2D C++ tutorials - Anatomy of a collision](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy)

Comment: If you notice the close-up image I posted, the platform is actually made up of smaller squares. My problem with contactListener happens when the ball is rolling off of one square onto another square in the same platform... endContact() happens between the ball and square #2 for example, before beginContact() happens between the ball and square #3. So the result is that from the program's perspective, the ball is not in contact with the platform, when in fact, it is. So that's why I chose not to use contactListener for this.

Comment: I just read the reason for not using the contact listener. I that case you need to call IsTouching on the fixture to check if collision happened.

Comment: Oh wow, excellent. That did the trick all right. Code works exactly as expected now. Many many thanks!

Comment: I know that you solved it using isTouching(), which is extra checking to see if the fixtures are actually touching... but based on what the Box2DDebugRenderer was showing, the AABB weren't touching in the first place anyway, so I still don't get why the text was turning yellow.

Would appreciate some further advice if it's not too much trouble. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help.
I see the problem with the contact listener and I have experienced something similar a while back, my levels where build of small squares as well. When the ball came in to contact with the wall a hit sound was played, so when sliding along the wall it was playing the sound like from a gun due to collision with each individual body. What we have done was to create the wall body as one square. We came up with an algorithm to read the level data and decide where and how big the blocks should be. This allowed using contact listener which is cheaper in runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure here, but maybe the AABB's in Box2D are bit bigger then the bodies them self. I know that isn't what the image is showing, but I really don't know that one.